# Creating a stack which deals with enum types?

Tags: objective-c, enums, stack

I have used the stack created at http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/226892/How-to-implement-Stack-in-Object-C, which will accept any object, but I actually want to use it to store an `enum` type.

When I was trying to assign an `enum` to it, the compiler said that `enum` cannot be converted into `id`. What should I do?

Comment: What type is the enum? if it is int you can wrap it inside a NSNumber.

Comment: I created a token type which is used to represent parts of the equation. such as NUMBER, BRACKET_LEFT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your stack stores NSObjects you can simply cast the enum values to an integer (which they are) and box them in an NSNumber:

**Adding to the stack:**

```
NSNumber *boxedValue = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:eMyEnumValue];
[stack push:boxedValue];
```

**Retrieving from the stack:**

```
NSNumber *boxedValue = [stack pop];
MyEnum enumValue = (MyEnum) [boxedValue integerValue];
```

Comment: Nah... It's a valid question. Now you'll never forget. :-)

Comment: Thanks by the way, otherwise I would be confused for the whole week.